# n-ary quadratic forms with $S$-integer values

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Let $Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n):=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$ be an $n$-ary quadratic form.

Given a finite set of (rational) primes $S$ is there an algorithm or theorem that describes all solutions to $Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=K$ subject to:

- the primes divisors of $x_i$ and $K$ all lie in $S$ and
- each $x_i$ divides $K$?

I would also be interested in the more general version where we allow positive integer coefficients.

Comment: S-integers usually mean rational numbers with denominators divisible only by primes in S. That is not what you are talking about in the body of your question. Also, what is the question?

Comment: If someone has studied the problem for S-integers then this will help as I can clear denominators. I have added a ? and a tag to make it clearer.

Comment: S-integers in the usual sense are allowed any integer numerators. What you are talking about is, I think, S-units. The S-unit equation (sum of S-units = 1) has been studied a lot with the main result being finiteness of solutions (modulo obvious conditions). You still haven't stated a question.

Comment: I am aware of the result of Evertse and others showing that there are finitely many solutions, even in the case of number fields.  I want to find all solutions if possible.